Problem with clicking on a submit button with selenium Python
In a web automation process with selenium Python, I am attempting to click on a submit button element. Despite being able to find the element and click on it, the code malfunctions when clicking on the button element. (See the attached pictures.  after clicking, the webpage gets white. The error occurs without a run time error)


Additional information:
The surrounding HTML code of web element is:
<input type="submit" value="ذخیره">

The part of the code involving in this issue is:
save_element= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='submit']"))).click()

This issue dose not arise when doing this process manually.(This issue also arises when trying to click the submit button on “automated window by using  ” time.sleep” command to halt the code process temporally).
The webpage log in  requires username and password and for confidentiality consideration, I can not public them to present the problem in a reproducible way.
Can you guide me on this issue?
